# Binding a property to an integer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've been reading a lot tutorials but somehow nothing works they mention about binding a property to a simple integer.

Here's the setup:

I got a user-control.
I want to bind "private int size" to the width of a border within the XAML-file.

Whats the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way you'd bind anything else:

```
<Border BorderThickness="{Binding Size}">
```

```
private int _Size;
public int Size
{
    get { return _Size; }
    set 
    {
        _Size = value; 
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Size");
    }
}
```

Of course your class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well.

Comment: OK I've done so, but it still complains that it can't find PropertyChanged

Comment: `public class MyUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged {`

Comment: You inherit from UserControl, not implement. INotifyPropertyChanged is an interface, and you can implement as many interfaces as you want.

Comment: Classes can implement multiple interfaces, even if inheriting from another class. Change it to `MyClass : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: OK I've done so, but it still complains that it can't find PropertyChanged

Comment: Also, @Hedge what @ceykooo's answer alludes to is that WPF does not allow binding to Fields, thus you must create a CLR Property (as shown) or a WPF Dependency Property.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: ah I c, now I've got the context

Comment: This won't work, because `BorderThickness` isn't `int`, but [Thickness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness.aspx)

Comment: @Danko Durbic: it actually will work as there is a Coercion from integer to Thickness provided by the dependency property.

Comment: I added "public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;" but changing Size just does nothing

Comment: @Hedge: are you raising the event when the Size property is set in the set{ } block?

Comment: Psychic debugging says the `DataContext` is not set. Slap an `x:Name=ThisControl` on the `<UserControl>` tag, and then change the binding to `{Binding Path=Size, ElementName=ThisControl}`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to declare a new **dependency property** and apply  **TemplateBinding**

Here is the control template, where I set bind the Size property to the width.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyUserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyUserControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBox Width="{TemplateBinding Size}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>



public class MyUserControl : Control
{
    static MyUserControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyUserControl)));
    }

    public int Size
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SizeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Size.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Size", typeof(int), typeof(MyUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(20));
}
```

Reference [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx)